# Swift iterate array with multiplier step

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of 100 items.
I want to iterate it with specific steps, 2n, 3n, 4n etc. For example, if n = 3, i want to iterate 3,6,9,12 elements of array.

How to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift you can do this with help of `stride`.

```
let n = 3

for index in stride(from: 0, through: 100, by: n) {
    print(index)
}
```

Output of the indexes:

```
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
30
33
36
39
42
...
```

Comment: thanks, but i also did achieve that with that :  for i in 0...tmp.count {
        
        if let numb : Number = tmp[p*i]{
            numb.isDeleted = true
        }
    }

Comment: yes but for the case that you describe it is more suitable to use syntax that I describe without usage of the own calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know swift but by the look of it from the basic swift loops this should do exactly what you want :

```
var i = 1
var n = 2
while i <= 100 {
    print(i)
    i = i + n
}
```